# How to create a HUGO page with no direct links

Tags: hugo

Is there anyway to create a hugo page which has no direct links? I would like to be able to create a markdown file for a page but only allow people to find the page if they have a direct link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. It really depends on how you are generating your pages. As for now I am showing two ways you can do it.

**Way 1**: Your _default/list.html generates the list of links to your content. You can customize that to exclude a link. Watch the *if conditional.*

```
{{ range .RegularPages }}
   {{ if (not in .Title "title of page to exclude") }}
    <li>
        <a href="{{.Permalink}}">{{.Date.Format "2006-01-02"}} | {{.Title}}</a>
    </li>
   {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

**Way 2:** Alternatively you can put an html file in the **static** folder of your hugo directory. If the directory does not exist, you can create it. No direct links will be generated for static contents unless you explicitly link to it from somewhere else.

Comment: This worked and just to expand a bit. I checked the theme I was using and it was rendering if this condition was met ```{{ range where .Paginator.Pages "Type" "!=" "page" }}``` Hugo assigns a "type" to the files in "content". So the type of files in contest/posts are of type posts. I simply made a page inside of a directory called content/page/ and my file did not render unless directly linked.

Comment: This does not work for RSS and sitemap.xml, so your page will still be easy to find. You also have to exlude them there in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all pages you do not want to list into a separate content sub-folder and not include it in the menu.

For example, my setup:

```
content
├── blog
├── notes
└── voice
```

Where only `voice` and `blog` have menu items, so everything in `notes` can not be accessed by links from the site.